# Matching django table foreign keys with filter function

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter

I'm trying to upload a csv into a django table. I am not able to match the data to the foreign keys. 'cpt' is the foreign key from price to service model. There are many price rows that map to one cpt row, but each individual row has only one cpt.

Here is my upload code.

```
path = "/Users/joannerodrigues/Documents/csv_import/"
os.chdir(path)
from catalog.models import Service, Price
with open('price.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)                             
     for row in reader:  
           p = Price(com_desc=row['com_desc'],
                     service=Service.objects.filter(cpt=str(row['cpt']))[0])
           p.save()
```

This is the error that I get:

```
site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 303, in __getitem__
    return qs._result_cache[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is what the data loooks like:
Price data: (header included in csv file)

```
com_des, cpt
"desc 1", '57647'
"desc 2", '87654'
```

Service data: (header included in file)

```
desc_us, cpt, price
"desc1....", '57647', '89.95'
"dsc2.....", '87654', '875.87'
```

Here are the models.py
Price

```
class Price(models.Model):
  com_desc = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null = True)
  service = models.ForeignKey("Service", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Service

```
class Service(models.Model):
    desc_us = models.TextField(blank=True, primary_key = True)
    cpt = models.IntegerField(default= 10000)
```

Comment: Hang on, you've contradicted yourself. You said `cpt` is the ForeignKey from Price to Service, but then you're looking up an integer field on Service, not the foreignkey. Which is it?

Comment: service is the foreign key for the Price class. I'm trying to merge the datasets on 'cpt' so I'm setting Price.service to cpt and trying to map it to Service.cpt

Comment: Well I still don't really understand, but never mind. Have you actually created the Service objects? What happens when you do `Service.objects.get(cpt=57647)`?

Comment: I can lookup elements in Service with filter, service = Service.objects.filter(cpt=87654)[0] gives me the service object.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Service.cpt` is an integer field so it would never match a string. You should convert `row['cpt']` to an integer instead for filtering:

```
service=Service.objects.filter(cpt=int(row['cpt']))[0])
```

Comment: Thanks!This still does not work. I get the same error

Comment: Wondering if the problem is the header?

Comment: I see. How is the Service data in the CSV file loaded into the `Service` model?

Comment: Same way and it loaded fine with the CSV. I can lookup elements in Service by CSV with filter, 
service = Service.objects.filter(cpt=87654)[0] gives me the service object

Comment: But, when I try to use the code above, I get "list index out of range" error

Comment: That error indicate that the filter returns an empty list. There must be some rows in your Price data whose `cpt` values do not have a corresponding entry in the Service data. Try logging the value of `row['cpt']` inside the `for` loop to see which value is failing to match.

Comment: It breaks immediately, no values match. I made the service dataset from the price dataset, so I know they all match. That's why I was thinking it could be the header, but when I use next(reader), it still doesn't work.